# Pasar datos de un archivo .JS a formulario PHP

Tags: php, json

No tengo muchos conocimientos en programación y no estoy seguro si lo que intento hacer es posible.

```
 $enviosss = $("#editarDireccion").val(); // variable en archivo .js
```

Esta variable `enviosss` toma los datos que se ingresan en un `input` de un formulario `.php`.

Ahora quiero tomar los datos almacenados en la variable $envioss del archivo `.js` y pasarla a otro formulario `.php`.

¿Es posible realizar este proceso?

Comment: ¿Pasar datos de un formulario a otro formulario? ¿Los formularios están en archivos distintos?

Comment: ¿Pasar datos de un formulario a otro formulario? // quiero pasar datos de un formulario a otro y los formularios se encuentran en archivos diferentes , estoy tomando los datos de un archivo php y lo paso a un archivo js y de este archivo js lo queiro pasar a otro archivo php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola para pasar datos de un formulario a otro por JavaScript es necesario que ambos formularios estén cargados en la vista del cliente, es decir, el campo de donde obtendrás el valor debe existir al igual que el campo en donde lo insertaras.

En tu caso seria por ejemplo:

```
var enviosss = $("#editarDireccion").val();

$("#editarDireccionForm2").val(enviosss);
```